# Speech Recognition Initialization Without Popup Window

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

When I try to initialize the "speech recognizer" with the following code:

```
SpeechRecognizer rec = new SpeechRecognizer();
```

there is a "set up speech recognition" pop up window that stop me from the initialization.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What that is trying to tell you is that Speech Recognition is not setup on your computer yet. You need to run through the setup wizard before you can use the `SpeechRecognizer`.

---

In playing around with the advanced speech properties(Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->Speech Recognition->Advanced Speech Options), when I set the Language settings to this it stopped running the program

[image]

Comment: @user1306633 I did not have the Speech Recognition installed on my laptop, when I tried to initialize the `SpeechRecognizer` in an console app it came up with the dialog box you are talking about. After running through each of the steps of the dialog, it allowed the application to run when I restarted it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I have followed what you suggested but I still unable to use 
speechrecognition in my code.

Instead, there is "speech recognition" program running at the center top of my desktop whenever I ran my program.

Comment: Does it say listening? or Sleep? or Off?

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the "speech recognition", an external program, from running?

Comment: i see "starting speech recognition" at the beginning and then "off".

Comment: @user1306633 See my edit, I was able to stop the external program from running by changing the language settings to what the Image shows.

Comment: Thank you for your effort in helping me.
I could not find the language you are using. The options I have are:
Microsoft speech recognizer 8.0 for windows(english-us)
Microsoft speech recognizer 8.0 for windows(english-uk)
Is there a way to add in the language you use?

Comment: @user1306633 I believe the version that I have came with office 2003, I think you are stuck with the version 8 recognizers. I am trying to find out if there is any way to disable the Gui

Comment: I appreciated your help. I solved my problem by initialize speech recognition instead.